# Parallel.For VS For. Why there is this difference?

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing

I have an array (i), and I want to do some math calculations based on the i value with a `Parallel.For()`.

But the problem is, after running the `Parallel.For()`, the values on my array are still 0.

This happens when my for is from 0 to 0.

This is my code :

```
    Dim a(10) As Double
    Parallel.For(0, 0, Sub(i)
                           a(i) = i + 2
                           'There is some calculations based on instead of previous line!
                           'But anyway, the result will be on a(i).
                       End Sub)

    MessageBox.Show(a(0)) 'This returns 0!


    For i As Integer = 0 To 0
        a(i) = i + 2
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(a(0)) 'But this returns 2!
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I said, this is not my calculations. my calculations are other thing. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @aehiilrs Question edited. read it again please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539.aspx#Y0)

*If fromInclusive is greater than or equal to toExclusive, then the method returns immediately without performing any iterations.*

Therefore nothing will happen when you use `Parallel.For(0,0,etc)`.

Try `Parallel.For(0,1)` and see if you get a result.

Comment: Very good catch! My brain was still stuck on what a normal loop would do from zero to zero!

Comment: I have tested. Parallel.For continues from fromInclusive to (toExclusive - 1) . Do you know why?!?

Comment: Because that's how it was designed. Imagine a C#-style for written like this:

for(i=fromInclusive; i<toExclusive; i++)

That's just how it is. :)

Comment: +1 Maybe it would have been clearer if Microsoft had called the method `Parallel.CSharpFor`! To be fair, the framework designers do usually think about *all* client languages, not just C#. In this case I suppose they just had to pick one definition of a `For` loop - they were bound to confuse some developers.

Comment: @MarkJ Thinking about it more, I'd almost bet they decided to go with the way that is the most reasonable when dealing with a zero-based array - that good old `for(i=0;i<arrayLength;i++)` situation that pops up so often.

Comment: @aehiilrs That pops up so often **in C#**. In VB the syntax is For i = 1 To arrayLength - 1

Comment: @MarkJ I think you have a bug there - but I do see your point now. That's gotta be awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Your correct code should look like this

```
   Dim a(10) As Double
    Parallel.For(0, 1, Sub(i)
                           a(i) = i + 2
                           'There is some calculations based on instead of previous line!
                           'But anyway, the result will be on a(i).
                       End Sub)

    MessageBox.Show(a(0)) '2!


    For i As Integer = 0 To 0
        a(i) = i + 2
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(a(0)) '2
```